# How to convert Joda LocalDate to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

What is the simplest way to convert a JodaTime [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) to [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### JodaTime

To convert JodaTime's [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()) to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), do

```
Date date = localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
```

To convert JodaTime's [`org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDate()) to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), do

```
Date date = localDateTime.toDate();
```

---

### JavaTime

To convert Java8's [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-), do

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

To convert Java8's [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-), do

```
Date date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

You might be tempted to shorten it with `LocalDateTime#toInstant(ZoneOffset)`, but there isn't a direct API to obtain the system default zone offset.

To convert Java8's [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-), do

```
Date date = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

Comment: For code safety, consider passing a timezone, because it will use the default one.

Comment: how to achieve this -->new LocalDateTime(Long.MAX_VALUE).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate, which causes  overflow on long

Comment: Running in to a very specific issue with this. Our server is located in Malta and I am now handling a case of someone born on 1973-03-31. When converting this with toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() it becomes 1973-03-31 00:00:00.000 which is a moment in time that never existed in Malta because of Daylight Savings Time. I could just add the time as noon and the problem would be solved, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to convert this, as I never actually use the time, only the date.

Answer (score 10):

Since 2.0 version LocalDate has a [toDate()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate%28%29) method

```
Date date = localDate.toDate();
```

If using version 1.5 - 2.0 use:

```
Date date = localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
```

On older versions you are left with:

```
Date date = localDate.toDateMidnight().toDate();
```

Answer (score 9):

You will need a timezone.

```
LocalDate date = ...

Date utilDate = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay( timeZone ).toDate( );
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this?

```
localDate.toDateTimeAtCurrentTime().toDate();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

new Date(localDate.toEpochDay())

Comment: Whilst toEpochDay() returns a long, and the Date constructor takes a long they are not the same thing. The Epoch Day count is a simple incrementing count of days where day 0 is 1970-01-01 (ISO). Whereas the constructor takes the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch". toEpochDay() gives you days, the constructor take milliseconds.