# Get value from Date picker

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to get the value from JavaFX datepicker and store the value as Date Object:

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
Date date = datePicker.getValue();
grid.add(datePicker, 1, 9);
```

Can you tell me how I can convert `LocalDate` to `Date`?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597671/how-to-convert-joda-localdate-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the name implies, LocalDate does not store a timezone nor the time of day. Therefore to convert to an absolute time you must specify the timezone and time of day. There is a simple method to do both, atStartOfDay(ZoneId). Here I use the default time zone which is the local timezone of the computer. This gives you an Instant object which represents and instant in time. Finally, Java 8 added a factory method to Date to construct from an Instant.

```
LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();
Instant instant = Instant.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
Date date = Date.from(instant);
System.out.println(localDate + "\n" + instant + "\n" + date);
```

This will give you an output like below. Note that the Instant by default prints in UTC.

```
2014-02-25
2014-02-25T06:00:00Z
Tue Feb 25 00:00:00 CST 2014
```

Of course, you will need to convert your java.util.Date into a java.time.LocalDate to set the value on the DatePicker. For that you will need something like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(date + "\n" + instant + "\n" + localDate);
```

Which will give you output like:

```
Tue Feb 25 08:47:04 CST 2014
2014-02-25T14:47:04.395Z
2014-02-25
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use more simplest way

```
java.sql.Date gettedDatePickerDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(myDatePicker.getValue());
```

And then you can perform operation within this date object.

Convert to `java.util.Date`

[Converting java.sql.Date to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066335/converting-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date)

Comment: It is not a perfect answer,because in case of the value is `null` ,it invokes an `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have IDE at hand but this should do the trick.

```
Date date = new Date(datePicker.getvalue().toEpochDay());
```

Or alternatively.

```
LocalDate ld = datePicker.getValue();
Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(ld.getYear(), ld.getMonthValue(), ld.getDayOfMonth());
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Comment: For reference, toEpochDay() seems to cause the date to be set to 01/01/1970, regardless of the value set in the datepicker

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly and just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

LeonidasCZ answer is not 100% correct: `java.util.Date` months range is from 0 to 11, but `Calendar.getInstance()` is from 1 to 12, so you can do this:

```
LocalDate ld = datePicker.getValue();
Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(ld.getYear(), ld.getMonthValue() - 1, ld.getDayOfMonth());
Date date = c.getTime();
```

If you want to add hours, mins, seconds too:

```
LocalDate ld = datePicker.getValue();
Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(ld.getYear(), ld.getMonthValue() - 1, ld.getDayOfMonth(), hours, minutes, seconds);
Date date = c.getTime();
```