# javafx: how to check if a date is greater than today's date?

Tags: javafx, datapicker, data-comparison

If I have:

```
DatePicker dp = new DataPicker();
```

and at some point I want to know if the data is greater than today, how can I do it?

Example:
if I want to book a room in a hotel from 21/04/2014 well, it should be impossible because today is 28/07/2014.

How can I do it in JavaFX ?

Comment: Have a look at `Date#before(Date)` and `Date#after(Date)`.

Comment: but it works with two Date objects. I have one DataPicker and one Date

Comment: `new Date()` constructs a `Date` containing the current date.

Comment: ok, I got it. The point is that I don't know how to make this expression to work: 
DataPicker dp = new DataPicker();


Date d = new Date();
if(d == dp.getVAl())...

Or somethig like this

Comment: Google for 'java datepicker get date' and find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446026/get-value-from-date-picker) among others...

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that a given `Date chosenDate` is after today, you can check

```
if (chosenDate.after(new Date())) {
    // valid (Date > today)
} else {
    // invalid (Date <= today)
}
```

Note that `chosenDate` should be a `Date` with hour, minute and second set to `0` since else it could accept a `Date` with the same day as today but a later hour than now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom method, which will compare given dates of given date format, and return `true`, when current date is "older" than your date of interest, eg:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(isDateOfInterestValid("yyyy-mm-dd", 
                "2014-08-25", "2014-08-28"));
    }

    public static boolean isDateOfInterestValid(String dateformat, 
            String currentDate, String dateOfInterest) {

        String format = dateformat;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date cd = null;  // current date
        Date doi = null; // date of interest

        try {
            cd = sdf.parse(currentDate);
            doi = sdf.parse(dateOfInterest);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long diff = cd.getTime() - doi.getTime();
        int diffDays = (int) (diff / (24 * 1000 * 60 * 60));

        if (diffDays > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And in context of pure JavaFX you can get the `String` value of `DatePicker` chosen date by calling `DatePicker.getValue().toString()`.

PS In case You have only one `DatePicker` object, You can use "hidden" method, which will check the current date. It can look like this:

```
public static String currentDate(String separator) {
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    String day = Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    String month = Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String year = Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    if (month.length() < 2) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if (day.length() < 2) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    String regDate = year + separator + month + separator + day;
    return regDate;
}
```

Comment: Och on reinventing the wheel there. `chosenDate.after(new Date())` does the same and is thoroughly tested.

Comment: Well, necessity is the mother of invention.

Comment: Yeah, but Javadoc is the mother of timesavers. Even then, `SimpleDateFormat#format(new Date());` saves you the entire method `currentDate`...