# Javafx Using Date Picker

Tags: java, date, calendar, datepicker, javafx

I am creating a Java Fx Application using Scene Builder. I have two Date Pickers Date1 and Date Two. I need to count the number of days between Date1 and Date2 excluding any Sunday. I have searched various answers but none that caters.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have problem getting dates from date pickers or computing the difference?

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl - Thanks for the post. I am using jdk8. I used the advised code and got 1.5046296E-4 based on using 01/09/2014 for Date1 and 14/09/2014 for Date2. I want to calculate the number of days between these days less Sundays (14 days less two Sundays in the Period so return 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
long date1 = datePicker1.getvalue().toEpochDay();
long date2 = datePicker2.getvalue().toEpochDay();
int  days  = (int) Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

Example:

```
long date1 = 16322; // 09/09/2014
long date2 = 16329; // 09/16/2014
int  days  = (int) Math.abs(date1 - date2);

System.out.println(days); // 7 Days
```

**Note:** I do not think jfx2.0 has a built-in DatePicker, so I am assuming you are using jdk8.

Also, I pulled the the `datePicker.getvalue().toEpochDay()` logic from this question:
[Stack Overflow: Get value from Date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446026/get-value-from-date-picker); which deals with jfx8.

The epoch in the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).[`toEpochDay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) is the number of days since 01/01/1970.

---

### Extra Credit

To Answer you question from the comment below, you could do the following.

```
int days = daysBetween(
    datePicker1.getvalue(),
    datePicker2.getvalue(),
    Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
);

public static int daysBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, List<DayOfWeek> ignore) {
    int count = 0;
    LocalDate curr = start.plusDays(0); // Create copy.
    while (curr.isBefore(end)) {
        if (!ignore.contains(curr.getDayOfWeek()))
            count++;
        curr = curr.plusDays(1); // Increment by a day.
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I am using jdk8. I used the advised code and got 1.5046296E-4 based on using 01/09/2014 for Date1 and 14/09/2014 for Date2. I want to calculate the number of days between these dates less Sundays (14 days less two Sundays in the Period so return 12)

Comment: *I updated my answer. See my updated answer.* Sorry, I did not really test the `toEpochDay` code... If the difference in your answer was `0.0001505` then you do not need to divide by 86,400.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is now calculating the number of days between the two DatePicker Dates. I only want it to count the number of days between the dates excluding counting for a Sunday. Eg. a 14 day period that contains two Sundays woudl only calculate as 12.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, int count has to be set to 1 in order to allow for 01/09/2014 -01/09/2014 to count as one day.  If the start date or end date is a Sunday it throws the number of days out by one.