# How to use Joda LocalDate and DateTime in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jodatime

I have downloaded the Joda jar and have imported 'org.joda.time.LocalDate' in my class. I have to get the current date and store it in the datastore.

```
LocalDate localdate = new LocalDate();
```

When i am trying to store the value in the datastore, I am getting error as

"date: org.joda.time.LocalDate is not a supported property type."

How do i resolve this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: `new LocalDate()` uses a default time zone. Since you are on App Engine, why not use `new DateTime()` instead?

Comment: The error "date: org.joda.time.LocalDate is not a supported property type." indicates, that the type (Java class) of the property with name "date" is not allowed as a property of an Entity. This is a technical problem (or better a restriction by the app engine) and has nothing to do with default time zones. Using the Joda DateTime class will cause exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at:
[Google App Engine (Java) -> Storing Data -> Datastore -> Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities)

In section "Properties and value types" you will find the supported/allowed property types. For date and time properties only **java.util.Date** is supported. This means you need to convert the **org.joda.time.LocalDate** to a java.util.Date instance before setting the property of an entity. Please refer on following post for conversation:
[How to convert Joda LocalDate to java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597671/how-to-convert-joda-localdate-to-java-util-date)